# Responsive file manager plugin image upload fails due to insufficient memory

Tags: php, responsive-filemanager

When I am trying to upload an image via Responsive Filemanager 9.11.3, I get "not enough memory" error. It returns HTTP 406 error code.

After looking out the solutions on the internet, I could verify following parameters are already set accordingly.

**php.ini**

> post_max_size = 100M
>
> upload_max_filesize = 100M
>
> memory_limit = 2G

**config.php (Responsive filemanager)**

> 'MaxSizeUpload' => 100,

However, I could not upload even a 232KB image. How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and, in my case, the solution was fairly simple: install the GD module. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I could found the issue. Some how I have updated my php.ini incorrectly in a past date. `memory_limit` value should be given in megabytes, not in gigabytes. So, after I change

> memory_limit = 2G

as

> memory_limit = 2000M

it worked fine.

I could also experience the "Not enough memory" issue when there are not enough permissions for thumbs folder. (I feel this is a bug in the plugin because it misleads the user by providing an irrelevant error scenario.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The memory error arises during thumbnail creation. I solved it by using a python script to resize/create thumbnails.